# Выделение активного якоря с половины высоты экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

В данном примере выделение активного якоря активируется когда секция располагается по верхнему краю экрана. А как можно сделать, чтобы якорь активировался, когда верх секции достигал половины высоты экрана (в т.ч. от центра)? И еще один момент, при клике на якорь, когда мы передвигаемся, нажимая поочередно на якоря снизу вверх, якорь выделяется верно. Но если двигаться сверху вниз, то якорь активируется неверно. Как это исправить? Благодарю за помощь!

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var $sections = $('section');
  $sections.each(function(i, el) {
    var top = $(el).offset().top - 0;
    var bottom = top + $(el).height();
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var id = $(el).attr('id');
    if (scroll > top && scroll < bottom) {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('active');

    }
  })
});
$("nav").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href'),
    top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 5px 5px 20px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.active {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#sec1" class="scroll-to">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec2" class="scroll-to">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec3" class="scroll-to">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec4" class="scroll-to">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec5" class="scroll-to">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="sec1" class="section">Секция 1</section>
<section id="sec2" class="section">Секция 2</section>
<section id="sec3" class="section">Секция 3</section>
<section id="sec4" class="section">Секция 4</section>
<section id="sec5" class="section">Секция 5</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var $sections = $('section');
var section_position = {}; //тут храним все верхние точки наших section
var screen_height = $(window).height(); //высота видимой страницы

checkPosition();

$(window).resize(function(){
  checkPosition();
});

function checkPosition(){
  screen_height = $(window).height();

  $sections.each(function(i, el) {
    section_position[i] = $(el).offset().top - 0;
  });
}

function toggleActiveClass(id) {
  $('a.active').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('active');
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var s_top = $(document).scrollTop() + screen_height / 2;

  for (key in section_position) {

    if (s_top >= section_position[key] || s_top <= section_position[key + 1]) {
      var id = $($sections[key]).attr('id');
      toggleActiveClass(id);
    }

  };

});

$("nav").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  id = $(this).attr('href');
  var top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 5px 5px 20px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.active {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#sec1" class="scroll-to">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec2" class="scroll-to">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec3" class="scroll-to">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec4" class="scroll-to">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec5" class="scroll-to">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="sec1" class="section">Секция 1</section>
<section id="sec2" class="section">Секция 2</section>
<section id="sec3" class="section">Секция 3</section>
<section id="sec4" class="section">Секция 4</section>
<section id="sec5" class="section">Секция 5</section>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' всегда пожалуйста))